# Can we run Spock Testcases and Junit 5 test cases together In one project?

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, build.gradle, spock, junit5

We are not able to run test cases written with **Junit 5** and **Spock framework** together in one **gardle project**?

We tried add dependencies given in https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-gradle to our gradle file. Gradle version is 4.10.3 and Junit 5. Below is my build.gradle file

```groovy
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    url "http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public/"
  }
  maven {
    url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public"
  }
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {

  compile group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version: '4.2.2'
  compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'

  testCompile(
    'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.8',
    'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4',
    'org.jmockit:jmockit:1.8',
    'junit:junit:4.12'
  )
  testRuntime(
    'cglib:cglib:2.2.2',
    'com.athaydes:spock-reports:1.2.7'
  )

  testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
  testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'

  testCompileOnly 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
  testLogging { showStandardStreams = true }
}
```

I have created two test cases, one is using spock framework and other is using junit 5. But when I do gradlew -test, it runs only test cases written with Junit 5. Below is build path.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need the Vintage test engine to execute Spock tests since they are based on JUnit 4, and you need the Jupiter test engine to execute the JUnit Jupiter tests.

So you need dependencies on both engines.

```
testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.3.1'
testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'
```

I'd also recommend that you upgrade to JUnit 5.5.1 (i.e., the latest and greatest).

Comment: Sam, Thanks for reply. I tried using vintage test engine, but now gradle is only executing spock test cases and junit test cases are not being executed. I need to run them both when I run "gradlew clean test" command.

Comment: You also need the `junit-jupiter-engine`. I'm sorry if my wording was unclear. I'll improve that now.

Comment: It worked... thank you so much... I will try to run some more scenarios...